Why I don't see an option to create a new metastore for unity catalog in Azure Databricks workspace
I have Azure pay-as-you go subscription. The login I am using to login to Azure portal has Global Administrator role. I have created Azure Databricks service in Premier Tier. I then launch the workspace by logging in using Microsoft Entra Id single signon. The workspace opens fine. Now I want to create a new metastore for unity catalog. So I click on the user account on the top right corner and look for manage account option in the drop down. But the manage account option is missing. So I cannot create a metastore for unity catalog.
Please help me to understand what is missing in my steps.


Are you using a premium plan?

Yes, I am using Premium plan.

The issue here is that the main user using which you login to Azure Portal does not have the Databricks Account Admin role. It has Global Admin role though.
By default Azure creates an external user for you which has the Databricks Account Admin role. Follow these steps:

Login to your Azure portal.
Navigate to Microsoft Entra Id -> Manage -> All users
Here you will see a user having EXT in the name. That is the default
external user for you.



Copy this username.
Logout from portal.
Open Azure Portal in a new Window.
Login to Azure portal again but this time using the external user you copied.
It will tell you that the password is incorrect.
Click on reset password.
Once the password is reset, login to Azure portal with the EXT user and the new password.
Navigate to Databricks service. Launch the workspace.
In the same browser window open a new tab and open the following URL: accounts.azuredatabricks.net



Click on Continue with Mircosoft Entra Id
Once in you can start creating the Metastore for Unity Catalog, etc.



You can check these requirements to create and manage catalogs:

To get started with Unity Catalog in Azure Databricks, the first Azure Databricks account admin must be an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Global Administrator.
When you log in as a Global Administrator into the Azure Databricks account console for the first time, they are automatically assigned the account admin role. After this initial setup, you no longer need the Azure AD Global Administrator role to manage Azure Databricks.
The first account admin can then assign additional account admins from the Azure AD tenant. These additional account admins don’t need any specific roles in Azure AD to perform their duties or to assign other account admins.
Here is the link to Login to ADB with Microsoft Entra ID.
Log in to the Azure Databricks account console using a Global Administrator account. Once logged in, you can ADD Users & groups.
Know more about Azure Databricks - Get started using Unity Catalog MS Q&A thread - How to access Azure Databricks account admin?
